# Algolia: Export React Instant Search results

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

Is there any way to export Algolia's React Instant Search results to a CSV? I've tried using the `react-csv` package, but it doesn't work with Algolia's `Hit Component`. The package requires `data` as props, but the data is constantly changing since it's React Instant Search.

What I mean by constantly changing is that on page load, you're given the entire index of records found, then you can narrow down the results with the search bar or other filtering components.

I've gone down the Google rabbit hole looking for information about exporting Algolia's search results as a CSV, but I haven't found anything regarding React Instant Search—unless I completely missed it.

Has anyone tried this before? If so, could you point me in the right direction regarding documentation or examples?

Comment: did this work btw

Comment: i wasn't able to figure it out and had to move on to plan b.

Comment: i see, too bad i was hoping it would work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem but one possible way is to use the [`StateResults`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/state-results/react/) widget. The `StateResults` widget provides a way to access the `searchState` and the `searchResults` of InstantSearch.
Here I will create a custom `StateResults` component in the form of a download button and then connect it using the [`connectStateResults`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/state-results/react/#connector) connector.

I have attached a demo below as well.
For simplicity I didn't format the data to be fed into the CSV builder.

```js
// 1. Create a React component
const StateResults = () => {
  // return the DOM output
};

// 2. Connect the component using the connector
const CustomStateResults = connectStateResults(StateResults);

// 3. Use your connected widget
<CustomStateResults />
```

In your case something like

```js
const StateResults = ({ searchResults }) => {
  const hits = searchResults?.hits;
  return (
    <div>
      <button>{hits && <CSVLink data={hits}>Download CSV</CSVLink>}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const DownloadButton = connectStateResults(StateResults);

//in your JSX then <DownloadButton />
```

[image: Edit Download Algolia Results to CSV]